# IE @font-face not working

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, font-face

I'm having issues getting ie to display my fonts correctly but they show correctly on Firefox, Safari, Opera, & Chrome. I used the website font2web to create the different font files and css files. I placed the fonts folder in the same directory as the css file that I'm working from and have looked through everything i can get my hands on relating to IE issues with `@font-face` but haven't had any luck.

The website is [thex-terminator.com](http://thex-terminator.com) and i'll post the relevant code below. Any pointers would be appreciated!

```
/** Generated by FG **/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_WarnockPro-Bold';
    src: url('fonts/WarnockPro-Bold.eot');
    src: local('☺'), 
         url('fonts/WarnockPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('emdedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/WarnockPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('fonts/WarnockPro-Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

`h1 {
    font-family: 'Conv_WarnockPro-Bold';
}`

Comment: Where did you get the font files? When using custom fonts, I've had font files actually be corrupted, and therefore not render properly.  Your css looks correct.  I notice you have other custom font faces - are you having the same problem with all of them, or are you just having issues with this one?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you do not have permission to use the fonts. If you check the Console in the F12 tool it gives the error:

> @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must
>   be installable.

I'm not sure if it is the font you are using that isn‘t licensed for use as a web font, or if the tool you used is setting the flags incorrectly. You can get a web font for Warnock Pro Bold from http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/warnock/bold/web-font